# How do I delegate building to a method?

Tags: html, groovy, builder, groovlet

I am writing a Groovlet and would like to delegate part of the HTML builder to a method but am having trouble getting it to work. Below is what I have:

```
def pages = [page1: html.p("page1")]
html.html {
  p("p")
  pages[page1]
}
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
<html>
  <p>p</p>
  <p>page1</p>
</html>
```

Instead what I get is the following:

```
<p>text</p> 
<html> 
  <p>p</p>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with the builder in question but I'd expect to be doing something like:

```
def pages = [page1: { p("page1") }]
html.html {
   p("p")
   delegate.with pages[page1]
}
```

Instead of `pages[page1]`, of course, you could call any closure or a `.&`'d method.

You need the `delegate.with` so that the closure you're running has its method calls (like `p()`) resolved to the delegate of the closure running it (that is, the `HtmlBuilder`).